# ColoredBox vs Container with color, what's the difference?

Tags: flutter, dart

Both code does the same job:

```
ColoredBox(
  color: Colors.blue,
  child: SizedBox.fromSize(size: Size.fromRadius(100)),
)
```

And

```
Container(
  color: Colors.blue,
  child: SizedBox.fromSize(size: Size.fromRadius(100)),
)
```

So, what's the benefit of using `ColoredBox` when it only supports just one property `color` which is also provided by `Container`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this has now changed according to this post:

https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/container-color

So actually just specifying only the `color` property in a `Container` would be optimised under the hood to `ColoredBox` by default now.

Unless I'm reading it wrong?

Comment: Yes, it's changed now.

Answer (score 1):

Your 2nd code

```
Container(color: Colors.blue, child: ...)
```

results in a widget hierarchy that uses a `BoxDecoration` to paint the background color.

`BoxDecoration` also covers many cases other than just painting a background color and hence it isn't as efficient as `ColoredBox` widget, which only paints a background color.

---

**TL;DR:**

If your use case is to only provide a background color, go for `ColoredBox` and not a `Container`.